# How to set the width/height of a plot in knitr?

Tags: r, plot, knitr

I have some R code, where I open a png() device to write a plot to, but I want this plot to also show in the PDF that I generate from the code using Knit-R.

So far, I have done this:

```
png(file="filename.png", width=5, height=5, units="in", res=300)
dev.control(displaylist="enable")
# Do the plotting here
dev.off()
```

This creates the `filename.png` with the plot in it, and it will also show me the plot in the Knit-R generated PDF, because of the `dev.control()` call. However, the size of the plot in the generated PDF is a bit off. I would like the size to retain the width and height ratio that I gave to the png() function. How do I do that?

**Note**: this is an R file, not an Rnw file. There is no LaTeX whatsoever, just R code, and I use the "File > Knit" command from R-Studio (Ctrl-Shift-K).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RStudio is running [knitr's `spin` function](http://yihui.name/knitr/demo/stitch/) on this, so you can write chunk options into an R comment above the code you're running. For example:

```
#-name, fig.width=5, fig.height=5
png(file="filename.png", width=5, height=5, units="in", res=300)
dev.control(displaylist="enable")
plot(rnorm(10))
dev.off()
```

This will produce a 5x5 image:

[image]