# how to change the plot area in Rmarkdown?

Tags: r, ggplot2, height, width, r-markdown

I have an RMD (Rmarkdown) file that plots (using gglopt2) a bunch of plots and makes a nice automatic HTML report. One of the plots in the report is this:

[image: my plot]

Sadly, as you can see, the histograms are all somewhat compressed in the y dimension, due to the limited space. As a solution, I think it might be cool if I will be able to double the height of the plot.

I have done some research and found this method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28392767/how-to-set-the-width-height-of-a-plot-in-knitr):

```
#-name, fig.width=5, fig.height=10
png(file="filename.png", width=5, height=10, units="in", res=300)
dev.control(displaylist="enable")
# plot your plot here
dev.off()
```

However, although it does effect the plot(ggplot object) command, it does not suit my need for the following reasons:

1. It creates the needed plot as a separate file, while I wish the plot would be embedded in the final HTML document made by the Render command.
2. The HTML file is not effected (positively).

I would appreciate any help you may give me finding the right way to do it :)

Comment: In the code chunk you run the plot add:" ```{r some name, fig.height = 10, fig.width = 5, fig.align = 'center'}"

Comment: I urge *against* using `png` and friends unless nothing else can be done. Use `fig.height` either in the chunk header (as @missuse stated) or, if you want/need it globally, use `opts_chunk$set(fig.height=9)`.

Comment: THANKS!!! you are great. it worked!

Comment: @r2evans may I ask what is wrong with ' `png` and friends ' and what would you suggest as an alternative (would those be the 'foes' ? ;) ? `ggsave`?

Comment: When you create a plot in something that supports vector graphics (e.g., latex/pdf), then the default capture of the plots preserves that; when you force raster with something like `png(...)`, it is always raster, and you are now responsible for a little more management such as plot size, resolution, etc. Similarly, I believe `ggsave` does the same, so it does not remedy that situation. I suggest you let `knitr`/`rmarkdown` do what they do well, and use one format when possible and the other format otherwise.